# Cannot add icon in a Chip

Tags: android, kotlin, icons, material-design, android-chips

I have implemented 3 `Chip` within a `ChipGroup` in my application successfully, but I am having trouble making an icon at the left appear.

```
<android.support.design.chip.ChipGroup
    android:id="@+id/chip_group"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/img_announcement_photo"
    app:singleLine="true"
    app:singleSelection="true">

    <android.support.design.chip.Chip
        android:id="@+id/chip_donate"
        style="@style/ChipStyle"
        android:checked="true"
        app:chipIcon="@drawable/ic_donate_black_24dp" />

    <android.support.design.chip.Chip
        android:id="@+id/chip_sell"
        style="@style/ChipStyle"
        app:chipIcon="@drawable/ic_sell_black_24dp" />

    <android.support.design.chip.Chip
        android:id="@+id/chip_trade"
        style="@style/ChipStyle"
        app:chipIcon="@drawable/ic_trade_black_24dp" />
</android.support.design.chip.ChipGroup>
```

But it doesn't show. I've tried programmatically as well, but no success. I am not yet using the new namespace, but the old `com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3` because I am also using Google Maps, and it is not yet supported by `androidx.*`.

Comment: What is @style/ChipStyle ?

Answer (score 15):

Try adding `app:chipIconVisible="true"` to your chip style .

Answer (score 10):

Actually since `app:chipIconEnabled` is deprecated it has to be `app:chipIconVisible="true"` now.

Answer (score 4):

If your style `@style/ChipStyle` contains
`style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice"` or `style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Filter"`, the icon will not show. I don't know what Google's reasoning is for this but I think is pretty silly.

Comment: I totally agree. But still you can make the icon visible with `app:chipIconVisible="true"`!

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was with setting `android:background` instead of `app:chipBackgroundColor`. That was making chip icon invisible.